# How do I use lightscribe when burning CDs and DVDs?

Tags: dvd, burning

I can I produce those nice images on the back of my dvd (lightscribe)?

Is it possible on ubuntu?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LightScribe

Comment: Whilst this may hypothetically answer the question, it would be preferable to add details from the article and keep the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance or forever--your answer would be worthless to a future user.

Answer (score 2):

I also found this very good tutorial on how to make lightscribe images on dvd.
I've ubuntu 9.10 and an external Dvd writer Samsung SE-S224

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=809112

It worked like a charm, only download links where slightly different.

http://www.lacie.com/us/products/product.htm?pid=10803

http://www.lightscribe.com/downloadsection/linux/index.aspx?id=1372